# Force Maven to use original versions on dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project `P` with a dependency `D` and a second dependency `A` that also has the dependency `D`. Not long ago, `D` was updated from version `4.2` to `4.4` with some features I would like to use. However, these features include an API change that breaks the functionality of `A`, if `A` uses version `4.4` of `D`. Therefore, I have to make sure that `A` continues with using version `4.2` of `D` and a version conflict arises. The pom for `P` looks like this:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <!-- A depends on D:4.2 -->
    <groupId>A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>D</groupId>
    <artifactId>D</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Looking at the dependency tree I get

```
[INFO] P:jar:3.0.2
[INFO] +- A:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- (D:jar:4.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.4)
[INFO] \- D:4.4:compile
```

I know that Maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins strategy, so it sees `D:4.4` first and resolves it for the project and omits other versions from transitive dependencies, that is the dependency from `A` (as stated in the tree).

I am wondering if there is a way to tell Maven that for my project `P` `D:4.4` should be used, and, at the same time, to avoid overriding the version for `A`, i.e. the original version `D:4.2` should be used for `A`. I have already played with the `dependencyManagement` without success.

Comment: Simple answer. No possible. No that simple answer: That not possible because in the end you have a class path (or a module path) which contains exactly one dep.. That means either D in version 4.4 or D in version 4.2 not both... in particular as you mentioned that there was a breaking change in the API (which is not reflected based on the version; violated semver etc.) ...In the end the only solution is to upgrade A to use the newer version and update your project in the end...

Comment: Okay, this is kind of what I expected. Thank you for the answer and clarification

Comment: The only way to achieve that would be the Maven shade plugin, but this is kind of a last resort solution.

Comment: Maven makes the assumption that any never version can replace any older version of an artifact.  Best bet is to fix A